# Java Quarkus, Create Generic CrudService

Tags: java, generics, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I want to create a java quarkus project by creating generic classes for myself except for the resource, so I don't have to implement the service and repository multiple times, just specify the entity classes and choose "standard" implementations. My error is that I get an exception when I want to add an object to the database, error: IllegalArgumentException: "Not an Entity" on TestEntity.

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("test")
@Tag(name = "Tests")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public class TestResource{
    
    @Inject
    private TestService testService;

    @POST
    public Response create(TestEntity te){
        Optional<TestEntity> t = testService.create(te);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(t.get()).build();
    }
}

@RequestScoped
@Transactional
public interface IBaseService<TKey, TEntity> {
    
    public Optional<TEntity> create(TEntity entity);
}

@RequestScoped
@Transactional
public abstract class BaseService<TKey, TEntity> implements IBaseService<TKey, TEntity>{

    @Inject IBaseRepository<TKey, TEntity> repository;
    
    public BaseService(){

    }

    public Optional<TEntity> create(TEntity e) {
        Optional<TEntity> result = repository.create(e);
        if(result.isPresent()){
            return result;
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class TestService extends BaseService<UUID,TestEntity> {
}

public class TestEntity {
    public String s;
    public int i;
    public Object o;
}

@ApplicationScoped
public interface IBaseRepository<TKey, TEntity> {
    
    public Optional<TEntity> create(TEntity entity);
}

@ApplicationScoped
public interface ITestRepository extends IBaseRepository<UUID,TestEntity> {
}

@ApplicationScoped
public abstract class BaseRepository<TKey, TEntity, TEntityDB> implements IBaseRepository<TKey, TEntity>, PanacheRepositoryBase<TEntity, TKey>{
    
    public BaseRepository(){
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<TEntity> create(TEntity entity) {
        if(entity == null){
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        this.persist(entity);
        return Optional.of(entity);
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class TestRepository extends BaseRepository<UUID, TestEntity,TestEntity> {
}
```

Comment: `TestEntity` is not an entity. You need to at least annotate it with `@Entity`

Comment: oh man what a mistake, I sit there several days on it and then the solution really thank you

Comment: You are welcome. I added my suggestion as an answer. It would be in the interest of future readers if you accepted it (assuming it solves your problem) so they don't have to read through the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestEntity is not an entity. You need to at least annotate it with @Entity